# CSS float-left prevent words to go on new line

Tags: html, css, css-float, floating

I have the following code:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="float-left">
        <a href="#"><img width="550" src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="float-left">
        <h1 class="new">Some long text here that should word wrap</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div>
```

**css**

```
.container{
    width:960px;
}
.float-left {
    float:left
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
h1.new{
    font-family: RockwellMT-Light;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 31px;
}
```

I want the divs to act like 2 columns One will be the image and the second one should be text that can go down as much as it takes.
Since float left does not have a fixed width the problem is that the whole element `h1` is jumping on the new line and the text does not goes on the next line.
I don't want to give fixed widths to the floating divs.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Can you add your whole css please?

Comment: It sounds more like you want to float the `<div>something</div>` from within the `<h1></h1>` so that the `h1` can be full width but wrap around the floated something div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove `class="float-left"` from the second `<div>` and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try smth like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="something">something</div>
    <div class="nextthing float-left">
        <h1 class="new">Some long text here that should word wrap</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div>


.container {
 position: relative;
}
.something {
 position: absolute;
}
.nextthing {
 text-indent: size_of_.something;
}
```

Or change float:left, to display:inline-block;